# Can't start localstack on Gitlab runner with LocalstackTestRunner

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, gitlab-ci, localstack

I have an issue of running Java integration tests with `LocalstackTestRunner` on Gitlab agent.
I've taken example from [official localstack site](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#integration-with-javajunit):

```
import cloud.localstack.LocalstackTestRunner;
import cloud.localstack.TestUtils;
import cloud.localstack.docker.annotation.LocalstackDockerProperties;

@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(services = { "s3", "sqs", "kinesis:77077" })
public class MyCloudAppTest {

  @Test
  public void testLocalS3API() {
    AmazonS3 s3 = TestUtils.getClientS3();
    List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
  }
}
```

and run it with help of gradle as `gradle clean test`.
If I run it locally on my Mac Book - all is ok but if it's run on Gitlab agent - there is an issue:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 [localhost.localstack.cloud/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
```

My gitlab ci job looks likes as follows:

```
Localstack_test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - docker:dind
  when: always
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean test --stacktrace
```

It happens that S3 client can't connect to `localhost.localstack.cloud:4566` because docker container created by `LocalstackTestRunner` is started within parent `docker:dind` container and AmazonS3 client can't access it. I've tried with other AWS services - result is the same - AWS client can't access localstack endpoint.

I've found some workaround as follows:

- add localstack as service in gitlab-ci
- add alias to it
- expose env variable HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=alias
- Make an implementation of `IHostNameResolver` to return my alias as HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL specified in gitlab-ci.

Something like that:

Gitlab-ci:

```
Localstack_test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - docker:dind
    - name: localstack/localstack
      alias: localstack-it
  variables:
    HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL: "localstack-it"
  when: always
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean test --stacktrace |& tee -a ./gradle.log
```

Java IT test:

```
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(
        services = { "s3", "sqs", "kinesis:77077" },
        hostNameResolver = SystemEnvHostNameResolver.class
)
public class MyCloudAppTest {

    @Test
    public void testLocalS3API() {
        AmazonS3 s3 = TestUtils.getClientS3();
        List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
    }
}

public class SystemEnvHostNameResolver implements IHostNameResolver {
    private static final String HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL = "HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL";

    @Override
    public String getHostName() {
        String external = System.getenv(HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL);
        return !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(external) ?
                external :
                new LocalHostNameResolver().getHostName();
    }
}
```

It works but as a result 2 localstack Docker containers are run and internal docker container is still not available. Maybe does somebody know better solution?

STR:

- gradle-6.7
- cloud.localstack:localstack-utils:0.2.5